# Concurrent Problem When process my business in SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, concurrency

A concurrent problem bothers me --- java rookie recently. It's that Multi users could make some requests to modify a data in database concurrently. But it's not allowed. Now, what I wanna resolve is --- Just ONE request can be passed if Multi Requests modify a data in database. But requests modifying different data concurrently should not be influenced. Just Search For Help to Optimize and get some good thinking.

```
  @ResponseBody
  @PostMapping("reportStreet")
  @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
  public AppJson reportStreet(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestBody QuestionDto dto) {
    QuCityPatrolQuestion question = quCityPatrolQuestionService.get(dto.getId());
      if("2".equals(question.getStatus())){
        return AppJson.fail().setMsg("Question Reported Before, Not Allowed!");
      }
    QuestionDto questionDto = new QuestionDto();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(question, questionDto);

    /**
    * some setter here
    */
    
    String resultStr = HttpClientUtils.doPostJson(GovplusConstants.REPORT_STREET, CommonUtil.entityToJson(questionDto));
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(resultStr)) {
      Map<String, Object> jsonMap = FastJsonUtils.json2Map(resultStr);
      String status = "";
      if (jsonMap != null && jsonMap.containsKey("status")) {
        status = (String) jsonMap.get("status");
      }

      // Here User reporting successflly wille get bonus score
      if (AppGlobal.RESPONSE_STATUS_OK.equals(status)) {
        User auditorUser = mUserMapper.get(AppUserUtil.getUserId(request));
        QuCityPatrolQuestion cityPatrolQuestion = new QuCityPatrolQuestion();

        /**
        * some setter here
        */

        ScoreManage scoreManage = new ScoreManage();
        
        /**
        * some setter here
        */

        scoreManageService.save(scoreManage);
        return AppJson.success().setMsg("No " + question.getIds() + " Successfully Reported");
      }
      throw new RuntimeException("ERROR");
    }
    return AppJson.fail().setMsg("ERROR");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is quite common. One option would be to add either optimistic or pessimistic locking to your application.
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-optimistic-locking

Another one would be the change the Transaction to be serializable. Your Database will the lock a dataset during a transaction.

```
 @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
```

This will however slow you application down a few milliseconds per transaction. Your transactions can now not be worked on simultaneously. You might want to choose a different isolation level depending on your specific use case.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation

Comment: Locking isn't required for 'serializable' behavior. Locking is a very old school way of implementing databases. Most modern databases use some kind of optimistic approach using MVCC instead of locking. The consequence is that transactions can fail due to the detection of non-serializable executions. Such a transaction should be retried and better luck next time.